# Terminology for standard notion of convergence for bump functions

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, terminology, smooth-manifolds

This is a terminology question about what I believe is a standard notion of convergence for sums of smooth, compactly-supported functions.

Let us begin by calling a sequence $(f_m)$ of smooth, compactly-supported functions on $\mathbb{R}^d$ **admissible** if:

1. the supports of the $f_m$ are uniformly bounded, and
2. for every multi-index $\alpha \in \mathbb{N}^d$, one has $\sum_m  \| \frac{\partial^\alpha f_m}{\partial x^\alpha}  \| < \infty$. Here $\| \cdot\|$ denotes the uniform norm.

Some basic properties:

- If $(f_m)$ is an admissible sequence, then $\sum_m f_m$ is also a smooth, compactly-supported function (the series converges uniformly and absolutely).
- Admissible sequences form a vector space, i.e. a linear combination of admissible sequences is admissible.
- Admissibility is a coordinate-independent notion. If $\theta:\mathbb{R}^d\to \mathbb{R}^d$ is a diffeomorphism, then $(f_m)$ is admissible if and only if $(f_m \circ \theta)$ is admissible. Ultimately, this coordinate-independence comes down to the fact that $\frac{\partial^\alpha}{\partial x^\alpha} (f \circ \theta)$ can be expressed as a finite sum $\frac{\partial^\alpha}{\partial x^\alpha} (f \circ \theta)=\sum_{|\beta|\leq|\alpha|} \left( \frac{\partial^\beta f}{\partial x^\beta }  \circ \theta \right) \cdot \theta_\beta$ where $\theta_\beta$ is a certain smooth function made up of partial derivatives of the component functions of $\theta$.

Now, it is straightforward to carry the notion of admissibility to the manifold setting. If $M$ is a $d$-dimensional smooth manifold, we can first declare that a sequence $(f_m)$ of smooth, compactly-supported functions on $M$ is admissible if the $f_m$ are all supported in a some chart neighbourhood $U \subseteq M$ and,  under some smooth identification of $U$ with $\mathbb{R}^d$, the sequence is admissible. Then, we can close the set of admissible sequences under finite linear combinations to get a notion of admissible sequence which doesn't require the sequence to be supported in a single chart.

We retain the basic properties above: admissible sequences of functions on $M$ sum to smooth, compactly supported functions; admissible sequences on $M$ form a vector space; and the space of admissible sequences on $M$ is invariant under diffeomorphisms of $M$.

> **Question:** I believe admissibility is a standard notion of convergence for a sum $\sum_m f_m$ of smooth, compactly-supported functions on a manifold $M$. What is a standard terminology for this notion? And, are there more shorter/better/more standard ways of defining it?